# Calling a function from controller to my view using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this two buttons.

```
 <div class="btn-group" ng-init="showData = 1">
     <button ng-model="showData" type="button" ng-class='{"btn btn-primary": showData == 1, "btn btn-white": showData != 1}' ng-click="showData = 1">Headline</button>
     <button ng-click="eventDescription()" ng-model="showData" type="button" ng-class='{"btn btn-primary":showData == 2, "btn btn-white": showData != 2}'  ng-click="showData = 2">Summary</button>
 </div>
```

In my controller I have a function that calls a WS, in the console I print a message just to make sure it's working and I'm able to see it,
             my function is something like this:

```
$scope.eventDescription = function () {

   some code goes here

    console.log("Service OK")

}
```

***The function code is not relevant so that's why I didnt put the code***

The thing is that when I click on the button to swith to that view nothing happens, I can't switch to that view so I dont get what is wrong if Im using ng-click.

Maybe I'm missing something but Im new to angular.

also I think this is relevant, depending on the button selection I call different directives (I render some HTML on them) like this:

```
  <head-line-view ng-show="showData == 1"></head-line-view>
  <summary-view ng-show="showData == 2"></summary-view>
```

Comment: it must be `ng-click="eventDescription()"`,  missing parenthesis

Comment: Actually I have it like that, I just update the question, in my console I got the correcto message but the issue is that I cant switch to the view in the "summary" button.

Comment: Are the buttons in the same scope as the ng-shows?

Comment: Your "Summary" Button has two 'ng-click' attributes.  that's not going to work.

Comment: @ajmajmajma yes, the are, actually I already notice that I have a previos ng-click, ng-click="showData = 2" for chosing the directives so I add a second ng-click but I also think this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 ng-click attributes in button tag, try this

```
 <button ng-click="eventDescription();showData = 2" ng-model="showData" type="button" ng-class='{"btn btn-primary":showData == 2, "btn btn-white": showData != 2}'>Summary</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I just notice the two ng-click but I didnt know how to call to different functions!!

This works perfect.  =)

Answer (score 1):

On ng-click on both buttons, it must call the function eventDescription.

In your original code ...
  The first button was just changing the value of $scope.showData. 
  The second button had ng-click twice, once doing 'eventDescription' instead of 'eventDescription()', and the other was changing the value of $scope.showData.

If on the button click you want the value of $scope.showData to be changed and to call the function $scope.eventDescription, you should just changet it in the function... You can, however, do this on ng-click as well

```
ng-click="showData = 1 && eventDescription()"
```

I'd prefer doing it in the function as it would take up less space in the html.

```
<div class="btn-group">
 <button ng-click="eventDescription(1)">Headline</button>
 <button ng-click="eventDescription(2)" >Summary</button>
</div>

$scope.eventDescription = function (viewNumber) {
    $scope.showData = viewNumber;
    console.log("Button Clicked");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it

=)

Answer (score 0):

Some points you can follow:

> 1. You should use `ng-model` for input fields not in others tag so should not use in button tag
> 2. Better to initialize in controller `$scope.showData = 1;`
> 3. `btn` class is common so use in `class="btn"` no need in condition

so you can try it like:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="showData===1? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-white' " ng-click="showData = 1">Headline</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="showData===2? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-white' " ng-click="eventDescription()" >Summary</button>
 </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.showData = 1; // initialize

$scope.eventDescription = function () {
   $scope.showData = 2; // set 2 for showData
   //some code goes here
    console.log("Service OK")
};
```